# Conmbining multiple row values and finding the Frequency and Percent

Tags: r

I am very new to R. I would really appreciate some guidance because I am not quite sure how to solve this:

Thank you for your reply. I will try to explain myself more clearly...

i have subsetted a variable in my dataset that has different dates:

Variable x ---> 2021-05-06, 2022-06-01, 2021-10-11, 2021-11-11, 2022-01-01... and i want to create a table of this variable showing a frequency count for dates in 2021 and 2022, and a percent.

My table should have 3 columns: A column for Value (with 2 rows 2021, 2022), another for Frequency and Percent. Does that make sense ?

Comment: I don't fully understand your explanation. Do you want to subset a single column of which the values are only dates? Or do you want to subset another column that associates with the dates column?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Generating sample data
set.seed(1)
test=round(runif(200,0,1))
temp=rep(as.Date("2021-01-01"),200)
temp[which(as.logical(test))]=as.Date("2022-05-01")

# Displaying frequency of each year
table(format(temp,"%Y"))

# Displaying frequency of each year as a percentage
table(format(temp,"%Y"))/length(temp)
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "break up the column into two groups," but if you simply want to output the frequency and percent,  you can just use `table()`